# is it possible to open a popup when a checkbox is checked using jquery?if yes how?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application i have popup box whichis initially hidden and there is a checkbox.so when a user checks the checkbox a popupup should open .please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just register it to your click event in the checkbox.

```
$('.myCheckBox:checkbox').click(function(){
    alert('Popup opening code goes here')
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#myCheckbox").click(function(){
   if($(this).is(":checked")){
     //Open Popup Window    
    }
});
```

Check this [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/GSZ8n/1/)